# Location Contextual Filter: Distance/Proximity

Tags: 7, views, location

I am trying to create a location-based contextual filter, and it seems like it should be taking four arguments - Lat, Lon, distance (number) and distance (unit).

How should this filter actually be created in the URL? I'm trying the following format:

42.279594,-83.732124,25, 2, miles

and getting nothing.

Would I just create a url with four arguments? Like location/%/%/%/%?

I've never used a contextual filter with multiple arguments before.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is this:

```
?distance%5Blatitude%5D=42.279594&distance%5Blongitude%5D=-83.732124&distance%5Bsearch_distance%5D=1&distance%5Bsearch_units%5D=mile
```